# Colors only change when random button is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing an Etch-a-sketch project and my problem is, the colors only change when I click on the random button, I want it to change whenever I hover to a different cell on the grid.

Here is a repl: https://repl.it/@antgotfan/etch-a-sketch
- This shows everything (html, css, js, and jquery)

link to what I want my etch-a-sketch to do: https://codepen.io/beumsk/pen/dVWPOW?editors=0110

I tried using event.target but I really can't wrap my head on what event is doing.

```
$randomButton.on("click", getRandomColors);
$resetButton.on("click", reset);

/*--------------------------- Corresponding to Event listeners ---------------------------*/
function getGradient(event) {

}

function getRandomColors() {
    let colorR = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
    let colorG = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
    let colorB = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
    $(".cell").hover((event) => $(event.target).css({
                                                    "backgroundColor": `rgb(${colorR}, ${colorG}, ${colorB})`,
                                                    "opacity": "1"}));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate the colour in the event handler(that is as the event is triggered) not before you bind the event handler.

```
function getRandomColors() {
  $(".cell").hover(function (event) {
    let colorR = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
    let colorG = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
    let colorB = Math.floor((Math.random() * 256));
    $(event.target).css({ "backgroundColor": `rgb(${colorR}, ${colorG}, ${colorB})`, "opacity": "1" })
  });
}
```

Comment: Wow... something that took me 2 days was solved in 10 minutes. Musa thank you so much, man! This means a lot. However, I am a little confused. What do you mean by binding the event handler?

Comment: When you call `getRandomColors` you are binding an event handler to the cells with the `.hover()` function before you do that you generate the colours.